# Can I check if a format specifier is valid for a given data type?

Tags: c#, .net, formatting

If I have (in .NET/C#) for instance a variable of type `long` I can convert it to a formatted string like:

```
long value = 12345;
string formattedValue = value.ToString("D10"); // returns "0000012345"
```

If I specify a format which isn't valid for that type I get an exception:

```
long value = 12345;
string formattedValue = value.ToString("Q10"); // throws a System.FormatException
```

Question: Is there a way to check if a format specifier is valid (aside from trying to format and catching the exception) before I apply that format, something like `long.IsFormatValid("Q10")`?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've not tried this but I would think you could create an extension method such as:

```
namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class MyExtensions
    {

        public static bool IsFormatValid<T>(this T target, string Format)
            where T : IFormattable
        {
            try
            {
                target.ToString(Format, null);
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }  
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

which you could then apply thus:

```
long value = 12345;
if (value.IsFormatValid("Q0")) 
{
    ...
```

Comment: Ouh, this looks good! (Although still basically checking for an exception it's encapsulated at only one single point.)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Okay... losing my mind. I need sleep... thanks for taking a look.

Comment: @Slauma: This now works, enjoy. [Lazarus walking off into the distance gibbering quietly to himself].

Comment: It seems that `null` and `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` makes no difference. (The CurrentCulture is the default for null according to MSDN.) I've tested for a few types and it works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Rather than creating a check for that I'd suggest that it might be better that the developers reads the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) to find out what's allowed where.

However, if there is a problem with a lot of typos being made, I suppose you could write a lookup table from the information on that page. Though that could just give you a false sense of security in that you'd get people making mistakes between valid format specifiers (writing an `f` but they meant `e` etc).

Edited to remove confused bit about TryParse/Parse.

Comment: As a crazy idea, suppose the format string is being provided by a user input. Also, not sure how TryParse vs Parse is relevant here, this is value to string not string to value.

Comment: I'm not sure how `Parse` or `TryParse` could help here. I don't need to convert a `string` to a `long` (or other type) but the other direction from `long` (or another type) to `string` with a given format specifier. The problem is that this format specifier is entered by users (who are probably programmers themselves) as a simple string in some text files (which can change quite frequently) and I often need to validate that this format is valid.

Comment: @Lazarus: TryParse vs Parse was just me getting confused, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @slauma: That's a bad situation, though I assume that you can do nothing about it (though I would suggest that it might be worth trying to get that changed to something more robust), and then I'd probably go with Lazarus solution.

Comment: @ho1: Indeed, I agree with you also that it's a fragile solution as currently architected and redesign might be the better solution.

Comment: @Lazarus: Your extension method made a redesign superfluous. I'm happy now with the architecture ;)