# Given string.format formatting string return the type

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to do a reverse type lookup on string.format formatting strings. Say for example I have {0:0.00} formatting string. It's used to format a decimal. Can I pass it to a function and have it return the type in this case decimal. Or pass {0:y yy yyy yy} and have it return DateTime?

Along the lines of this ([Can I check if a format specifier is valid for a given data type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408540/can-i-check-if-a-format-specifier-is-valid-for-a-given-data-type)) but for String.Format and I can't pass in the type I'm looking for. I guess I can have a list of types to try against.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
I'm reading data from database that always comes in as string. I don't know its type. I want to fit it into some other database where I do know what type it's supposed to be. The way I know the type is because somebody has provided a string.format parameter. They don't provide a type just the string.format parameter. So I was trying to see if I can get the type from the formatting provided. I realize this is a bad design but that's what I'm forced into.

Comment: You can of course make a function do most anything you want. You just need to determine the rules you will work with, especially since some format strings are valid for many types. {0.00} can be used to format any numerical type, so you'd have to choose the best fit.

Comment: What is the context in which you need to use this?   If you have the variable that is being formatted then they not just get the type directly?

Comment: please see edit in the question

Comment: I would suggest that you do a distinct select of all the possible format strings and then manually map them ...

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to do a work around to get it going for now and look at a design change to fix it for good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never come across anything like this, nor would it be possible in the absolute. Some format strings will work for more than one type. I am going to say there is nothing out of the box to do this.

If you look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) most of the numeric formats will work for any numeric type, int, float,  double, decimal... A few will as you point out only work with dates, but it would be difficult to design a good API for describing that.

As the commentators have said here if you post a question that more broadly reflects what you are trying to achieve you may get some better ideas.